# Facebook Open Graph Not Picking Up Meta Tags On One Page Only

Tags: wordpress, facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, curl

Open Graph works perfectly fine on **all pages on my site** except this one page and I haven't been able to figure out, for the life of me, why! It was working fine previously but suddenly stopped working one day.

URL:
https://dietbros.com/fat-burning/the-ultimate-fat-burning-foods-list/

From the Facebook Sharing Debugger:
**Object Missing a Required Value**
"Object at URL 'https://dietbros.com/fat-burning/the-ultimate-fat-burning-foods-list/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided."

If you check the link, the "og:type" is "article" and not website like the sharing debugger suggests.

When using the object debugger, I get the following error:
"Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received" but the page finishes loading <5 seconds (I even shared a screencast of that with the Facebook Developers in the thread I created).

I've tried the following:

- Used the sharing debugger multiple times
- Tried the "Scrape Again" multiple times with no effect
- Cleared my website cache, browser cache, used different browsers, etc. to no avail
- Tried the "Object Debugger" and attempted the "Fetch new scrape information" option, no luck here as well.
- Contacted my host (Hostgator) if there was any problem at their end and to see whether they were blocking any Facebook crawler IPs, but they said none of Facebook's crawler's IPs have been blocked and they're serving millions of sites with no issues.
- Created a thread in the Facebook Developers Forum and they gave me
  the following response from them:
  "We checked our curl request and can confirm your site isn't open to our server. Here's some logs:

  [xiaofb@devvm29992.prn1 ~/www] curl -v --compressed -H 'Range: bytes=0-524288' -H 'Connection: close' -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+ttp://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "ttps://dietbros.com/fat-burning/the-ultimate-fat-burning-foods-list/"

  - Trying 2400:cb00:2048:1::6818:74e2...
  - TCP_NODELAY set
  - Trying 104.24.117.226...
  - TCP_NODELAY set
  - Immediate connect fail for 104.24.117.226: Network is unreachable
  - Trying 104.24.116.226...
  - TCP_NODELAY set
  - Immediate connect fail for 104.24.116.226: Network is unreachable
  - Trying 104.24.117.226...
  - TCP_NODELAY set
  - Immediate connect fail for 104.24.117.226: Network is unreachable
  - Trying 104.24.116.226...
  - TCP_NODELAY set
  - Immediate connect fail for 104.24.116.226: Network is unreachable
    ^C
    [xiaofb@devvm29992.prn1 ~/www] ping 104.24.116.226
    connect: Network is unreachable
    [xiaofb@devvm29992.prn1 ~/www] traceroute 104.24.116.226
    traceroute to 104.24.116.226 (104.24.116.226), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
    connect: Network is unreachable

You may want to look into your network settings to open up the access to our crawler."

**Note:** Have removed the "h" in the http and https in the above code to stay below the 2 links limit that I'm allowed as a new user. :)

Again, this is the only page where I'm having this issue. If you check any of the other pages on the site, you'll see that the meta tags are picked up perfectly by Open Graph and it works wonderfully well.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to remove those links, and replace them with 'abcde.xyz' or something similar, as those - in conjunction with your user name - could very well be perceived as self-promotion, which is forbidden.

Comment: Remove which links? Are you talking about the links in the log? Those links are there only because they're a part of the log that was posted by a Facebook developer in the thread I had created and thought it would help put across the issue better. Would the log still make sense if I took off those links? I'm just looking for a solution to this issue. I wouldn't mind taking down the post once it's resolved as well if there's any inkling of me trying to get some mileage out of this! :)

Comment: Any help with this would be absolutely great and will be greatly appreciated! :)